# Mysql insert column and data from one table based on EXISTS

Tags: mysql

Not sure why this won't work, trying to insert column(from table) and data(not from any table) from one table into another IF it isn't already there.

```
INSERT INTO event_tags ( event_id, tag_id ) 
VALUES (SELECT  events.id, 2 FROM events WHERE events.info = 'HybridAnalysis') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT events.id=event_tags.event_id AND event_tags.tag_id=2);
```

Tables

```
Events
id  Info
1           ThreatExpert
2           HybridAnalysis
3           ThreatExpert
4           HybridAnalysis 

Event_tags
event_ID    tag_id
3           1
4           2
```

(eventsID is not primary)

Event_tags(table) should end up looking like this -

```
Event_tags
event_id    tag_id
3           1
4           2
1           1
2           2
```

This is my error - ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT  events.id, 3 FROM events WHERE events.info = 'HybridAnalysis') WHERE NOT' at line 2

*Edited below

##### There is a tags table I didn't realize that might make it easier

```
tags
id    name
3     HybridAndlysis
4     ThreatExpert
```

Comment: the syntax is either 1) insert tbl(col1,col2) values (a,b) ... or 2) insert tbl(col1,col2) select x,y from ...

Comment: are threatExpert and HybridAnalysis the only two values you will ever enter?  Is there a pattern?  Is it always 1,2 as tag_id for these?  otherwise you have to update this query for new info and tag_ids

Comment: @EoinS those are the only two I have right now, I need to do the same for ThreatExpert and then just run a cron job each night.   But yeah there could be more later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
INSERT INTO event_tags ( event_id, tag_id ) 
SELECT  events.id, 2 
FROM events AS E
WHERE E.info = 'HybridAnalysis'
AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 
  1 
FROM  event_tags AS ET 
WHERE E.id=ET.event_id AND ET.tag_id=2
);
```

Second Answer based on info column from Event table

```
    INSERT INTO event_tags ( event_id, tag_id ) 
    SELECT  events.id, 2 
    FROM events AS E
    WHERE E.info = 'HybridAnalysis'
    AND NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 
      1 
    FROM  event_tags AS ET 
    INNER JOIN events AS E1
    E1.event_id=ET.event_id
    WHERE E1.info = 'HybridAnalysis'
    );
```

Comment: That did it, I just had to modify the events.id to id and it seems to work fine.  Now the same thing for threatexpert and I'm done!!   What does the SELECT 1 do?  What is the 1?   Many thanks and man I'm tired.

Comment: Select 1 just checks if value is returned from the subquery or not. If no/null value returned from subquery it will insert records in event_tags table. Hope this helps.

Comment: what happens if there is a 'HybridAnalysis' insert with a Tag_id of 5?

Comment: In that case instead of tag_id we can use filter based on info column from events table.

Comment: @Sandesh Ah, that trick alone was worth this whole post.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So you can use this to accept either ThreatExpert or HybridAnalysis and it will enter them in the `Event_tags` table if not already present:

```
INSERT INTO event_tags ( event_id, tag_id ) 
SELECT  
events.id,
(case when E.Info = 'HybridAnalysis' then 1 when E.Info = 'ThreatExpert' then 2 else 0 end)
FROM events AS E
WHERE
NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 
1 
FROM  event_tags AS ET 
WHERE E.id=ET.event_id
);
```

If there is a new `info` that should have an alternative tag_id the CASE statement will insert 0 into the table.

Your case statement can be updated to handle new `info` entries.  Ideally the `tag_id` could be stored somewhere in `events` table or in a link table.

Comment: that works too!  Hah, yes there is a tags table would that have made it easier?   I'll add it to the orig post.